# Is it possible to nest functions in an object in a prototype and access the base object?

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

#### Update: I can't answer the question, since it's locked, but I have my own solution to this problem at the bottom, working with [Jonas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68366875/3917091)

Suppose I have this addition to a prototype. I'll use HTMLElement as an example.

```
HTMLElement.prototype.MyNamespaceGetThis = function() {
  return this;
}
```

`document.body.MyNamespaceGetThis()` will return `document.body`

But if I want to nest it in an object

```
HTMLElement.prototype.MyNamespace = {};
HTMLElement.prototype.MyNamespace.GetThis = function() {
  return this;
}
```

`document.body.MyNameSpace.GetThis()` will return `document.body`'s `MyNameSpace` (`{GetThis: ƒ}`)

#### **Is there a way to make `this` or any variable return a reference to the base-object? `document.body` in this case?**

I've tried a few variants, like

```
HTMLElement.prototype.MyNameSpace = (function() {
  let that = this
  let obj = Object.defineProperties({}, {GetThis: {
    value: function() {
      console.log(that)
    },
    enumerable: false}})

  return obj;
})()
```

but this fails for completely understandable reasons. The function is only run once and returns a reference to `window`

I've tried a few experiments with `.bind()`, but none return the desired result, for predictable reasons.

---

### My Solution

What I didn't like about Jonas' answer, was that it's basically the same as `MyNamespace().method`, where `MyNamespace` returns a set of methods.

Persisting members are also impossible. If I wanted to store member data, I needed a separate object somewhere to do that, and I didn't like that.

My solution was to use a `class` and then invoke it in a special memory-light way.

```
class MyNamespace {
  constructor(parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }

  GetThis() {
    return this.parent;
  }
}
```

And then, for this example, you add it to the HTMLElement prototype like this

```
Object.defineProperties(HTMLElement.prototype, {
    MyNamespace: {
      enumerable: false, writeable: true,
      get: function() {
        let ret = new MyNamespace(this);
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'MyNamespace', {
          enumerable: false,
          writeable: false, // note about this
          value: ret
        });
        return ret;
      },
      enumerable: false, writeable: false
    },
  })
```

The first call to say, `document.body.MyNamespace.GetThis()` will return a new instance of the class `MyNamespace` and then invoke `GetThis()` from that. It will also change `document.body`'s `MyNamespace` to directly reference the created instance, rather than create a new one each time. This means persistent data.

Something else I like about this, is that each element isn't carrying around a full `MyNamespace` instance, unless it's called upon in the life of the document.

Once the reference is updated, I have it set to freeze it so that it can't be overwritten, but it's easy to imagine where a person might want a `destroy` method. You would change `writable` to true and something like this.

```
class MyNamespace {
  constructor(parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }

  GetThis() {
    return this.parent;
  }

  destroy() {
    Object.defineProperties(HTMLElement.prototype, {
        MyNamespace: {
          enumerable: false, writeable: true,
          get: MyNamespace.factory(this, true),
          enumerable: false, writeable: false
        },
      })
  }

  renew() {
    this.parent.MyNamespace = MyNamespace.factory(this.parent, true)
    // HTMLElement.prototype.MyNamespace can also be set
    // to MyNamespace.factory(this)
  }

  static factory(parent, writeable) {
    return Object.defineProperty(parent, 'MyNamespace', {
      enumerable: false, writeable: writeable,
      value: new MyNamespace(parent)
    }).MyNamespace;
  }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn `MyNamespace` into a getter and store a reference to the parent:

```
function Namespace(parent) {
   return {
     parent,
     /* Your functions here */
   };
 }

Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, "namespace", {
  get() { return Namespace(this); },
});

console.log( 
  document.body.namespace.parent === document.body // true
);
```